# Definition of a bounded subset in a normed vector space

Tags: real-analysis, definition, normed-spaces

I'm having a hard time trying to understand what is exactly a bounded set (or subset) in a normed vector space.

This is where I am so far in my "understanding":

- Let $(V, \|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space. We can define $\|y-x\| =: d(x,y) =: d$ such that $(V,d)$ is a metric space.
- In a metric space (such as in $(V,d)$), a set $A$ is bounded if it is contained in a ball of finite radius, that is: $A \subset V$ is bounded if there exists $x \in V$ and $0 < R < \infty$ such that $A \subset B(x,R)$, i.e. such that $d(x,y) \le R$ for all $y \in A$.
- A set in a topological vector space (such as a normed vector space) is called bounded if every neighborhood of the zero vector can be inflated to include the set. (Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set_(topological_vector_space)))
- Apparently, a subset $A$ of a normed vector space $(V, \|\cdot\|)$ is said to be bounded if there exists $C > 0$ such that $\|v\| \le C$ for all $v \in A$.

What I don't understand is that, to me, it would be "logical" to say that a subset $A$ of a normed vector space $(V, \|\cdot\|)$ is bounded if there exists $x \in V$ and $C>0$ such that $d(x,y) = \|y-x\| \le C$ for all $y \in A$. But it seems like the "real" definition of a bounded (sub)set of a normed vector space is considering only $x=0$, that is, $x$ being the zero vector. Why is that?

Furthermore, I'm not sure to understand the definition given by Wikipedia. Since a neighborhood is a set containing an open set containing a particular point, and considering that this point could be the zero vector, how can we use that information to get the actual definition of a bounded subset of a normed vector space (i.e. the last definition I mentioned in my list above)?

As you can see, I'm quite confused about all this... And I'm a little bit exhausted since I've tried to get it for hours now. Any help would be greatly appreciated...!

Answer (score 6):

It's the same.
Let $(V, \|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space and let $A\subset V$.
If there exist $x\in V$ and $R > 0$ such that $A \subset \overline{B}_R(x)$, then you have
$$
\|y\| \leq \|y-x\| + \|x\| \leq R + \|x\| =: C
\qquad \forall y \in A,
$$
hence $A$ is bounded in the sense of your first definition.

Comment: Jesus I'm such an idiot. I actually found that $\| y \| \le R + \| x \|$ but I didn't think of defining it as $C$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: To add to the answer, observe that $B(x_0, r) \subseteq B(x, r + \| x_0 - x \|)$ for all $x$

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. But I got it clear by understanding that from the actual definition of a bounded set A in a normed linear space  it can be proved that A is contained in a closed sphere and vice versa. Let's see the proof,
Our claim is in a normed linear space E , a set A is bounded iff A is contained in a closed sphere S[€,0] with centre origin .
 Proof:-  if a is bounded then there exists a∈E and K>0 such that d(x,a)=||x-0||< or = K for all x∈A 【this is the actual definition of a bounded set in a normed linear space】
But then ||x-0|| =||x||≤||x-a||+||a||≤K+||a||for all x∈A, and hence A is a subset of S[€,0], where € = K+||a||
On the other hand if A is a subset of S[€,0], then for any x∈A,
d(x,0)=||x-0||≤€. Hence A is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

There is an important distinction that has not been made here yet. While the definition for boundedness in a normed vector space and boundedness in the metric space induced by that norm do coincide, the bounded sets in a topological vector space and the bounded sets in the metric space induced by some compatible metric need not be the same.

Rudin goes into the details in *Functional Analysis* section 1.29.